# Vuetify - getAttribute of data attribute in a component returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Just starting with Vue and need some advice on best practices.

I am trying to add a simple data attribute to Vuetify button.

```
<v-btn @click="btnClick" data-post="p123">Blue Button</v-btn>
```

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data() {
      return{
     }
      },
  methods:{
        btnClick(e) {
           console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-post'));
        }
    }
```

On button click I am getting a `null` value.
Is there something wrong I am doing above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below. `currentTarget` property gives you parent element of the target click. thereby you can get the attribute.

```
methods: {
        btnClick(e) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.post);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `v-btn` is a component not a native html element that could be handled as target for some events, in order to achieve the same behavior add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to that component like `<v-btn ... ref="btn">..` and access the attribute as `this.$refs.btn.$el.getAttribute('data-post')` :

**Full exampele**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods: {
    btnClick(e) {
      console.log(this.$refs.btn.$el.getAttribute('data-post'));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-btn @click="btnClick" data-post="p123" ref="btn">Blue Button</v-btn>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```